# Speed up lookup item in list (via Python)

Tags: python, performance, list

I have a very large list, and I have to run a lot of lookups for this list. 
To be more specific I work on a large (> 11 Gb) textfile for processing, but there are items which are appear more than once, and I have only process them first when they are appearing. 
If the pattern shows up, I process it, and put it to a list. If the item appears again, I check for it in the list, and if it is, then I just pass to process, like this:

```
[...]
if boundary.match(line):
    if closedreg.match(logentry):
       closedthreads.append(threadid)
    elif threadid in closedthreads:
        pass
    else:
[...]
```

the code itself is far from optimal.  My main problem is that the 'closedthreads' list contains a few million items, and the whole operation just start to be slower and slower. 
I think it could be help to sort the list (or use a 'sorted list' object) after every append() but I am not sure about this. 
What is the most elegant sollution?

Comment: As the answers so far indicate, it would be helpful to know more about ´threadid´: Which type it is, if the values are constrained somehow … in the end, you'll need some fast lookup, hence hashing, and in some cases, crafting your own hash function might be the way to go; domain knowledge helps there.

Comment: The threadid is a simple integer number. (I processing a lot of mysql_slow.log files to re-run them on servers with percona-playback. To speed up the replay process I have to close the threads which are appearing last on the logs.

Comment: Then the accepted answer is likely to do just fine. If you still have speed issues then, it'd be time to have a closer look at those numbers. Or rather solve the actual problem some different way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a set instead of a list will give you O(1) lookup time, although there may be other ways to optimize this that will work better for your particular data.

```
closedthreads = set() 
# ...

if boundary.match(line):
    if closedreg.match(logentry):
       closedthreads.add(threadid)
    elif threadid in closedthreads:
        pass
    else:
```

Comment: Thanks for the example too. (I've accepted the other answer, because it was faster.)

Comment: :( sorry dude, next time then

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a set or a hash table which marks if given id already appeared. It should solve your problem with O(1) time complexity for adding and finding an item.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to preserve ordering?

If not - use a set.

If you do - use an OrderedDict. OrderedDict lets you store values associated with it as well (example, process results)

But... do you need to preserve the original values at all? You might look at the 'dbm' module if you absolutely do (or buy a lot of memory!) or, instead of storing the actual text, store SHA-1 digests, or something like that. If all you want to do is make sure you don't run the same element twice, that might work.

Comment: I'd guess that a thread ID is probably shorter than its SHA1 hash (although OP doesn't give enough information), and that the hashing operation itself would be too computationally expensive.

Comment: yes, this is true - for some reason, i was thinking the original items were strings. in that case, it may not really be that much slower, and may even be faster (since to check if an item is in the set, you have to call both `__hash__` and `__eq__`, and string equality isn't necessarily low impact on long strings)....